# Grunt error "task default not found"

Tags: gruntjs

I am create gruntfile and install all needed dependencies.
In tutorial all worked fine but not for me.
If i try to run this gruntfile i see this error message:

> > Error: Cannot find module 'pixrem'
> >       Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
> >       Aborted due to warnings.

Where is mistake? If you can please correct the mistakes in the answer.
  Gruntfile is here:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 grunt.initConfig({
  pkg : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  watch : {

   images : {
    files : ['images/src/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
    tasks : ['newer:imagemin']
   }, // watch images added to src

   deleting : {
    files : ['images/src/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
    tasks : ['delete_sync']
   }, // end of delete sync

   scripts : {
    files : ['js/libs/*.js', 'js/custom/*.js'],
    tasks : ['concat', 'uglify'],
    options : {
     spawn : false,
    }
   }, //end of watch scripts

   css : {
    files : ['sass/**/*.scss'],
    tasks : ['sass', 'postcss', 'penthouse'],
    options : {
     spawn : false,
    }
   }, //end of sass watch

   grunt : {
    files : ['gruntfile.js']
   }
  }, //end of watch

  /* ====================================================================================================================================================
   * ====================================================================================================================================================

   Tasks

   ====================================================================================================================================================
   ====================================================================================================================================================
   */

  delete_sync : {
   dist : {
    cwd : 'images/dist',
    src : ['**'],
    syncWith : 'images/src'
   }
  }, // end of delete sync

  imagemin : {
   dynamic : {
    files : [{
     expand : true, // Enable dynamic expansion
     cwd : 'images/src/', // source images (not compressed)
     src : ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'], // Actual patterns to match
     dest : 'images/dist/' // Destination of compressed files
    }]
   }
  }, //end imagemin

  concat : {
   dist : {
    src : ['js/libs/*.js', 'js/custom/*.js'],
    dest : 'js/build/production.js'
   }
  }, //end concat

  uglify : {
   dist : {
    src : 'js/build/production.js',
    dest : 'js/build/production.min.js'
   }
  }, //end uglify

  sass : {
   dist : {
    options : {
     style : 'nested', //no need for config.rb
     compass : 'true'
    },
    files : {
     'css/main.css' : 'sass/main.scss'
    }
   }
  }, //end of sass

  postcss : {
   options : {
    map : true,
    processors : [require('pixrem')(), // add fallbacks for rem units
    require('autoprefixer-core')({
     browsers : 'last 2 version, IE 9'
    }), // add vendor prefixes. for more: https://github.com/ai/browserslist
    require('cssnano')() // minify the result
    ]
   },
   dist : {
    src : 'css/main.css'
   }
  },

  penthouse : {
   extract : {
    outfile : 'css/critical.css.php',
    css : 'css/main.css',
    url : 'http://localhost/grunt-boilerplate',
    width : 1200,
    height : 500
   },
  }, //end of penthouse

  browserSync : {
   dev : {
    bsFiles : {
     src : ['css/*.css', 'images/*.*', 'js/build/production.min.js', '*.php', 'includes/*.php', '!.sass-cache']
    },
    options : {
     proxy : "localhost/grunt-boilerplate",
     watchTask : true
    }
   }
  },

  ftpush : {
   build : {
    auth : {
     host : 'ftp.yourwebsite.com',
     port : 21,
     authKey : 'key1' //ftp login is in the .ftppass file
    },
    src : './', //root
    dest : '/www', //destination folder
    exclusions : ['.sass-cache', '.git', 'images/src', 'node_modules', '.gitignore', '.ftppass', 'gruntfile.js', 'README.md', 'package.json'], //remember adding '.ftppass' to the exclusions in .gitignore if you are publishing the repo to github
    // keep : ['blog','cv','projects'], // SUPER IMPORTANT! check what resources should STAY on the server, for example your wordpress installation or other subfolders you use for other projects. else they'll get wiped out
    simple : false,
    useList : false
   }
  }
 });

 // load npm tasks
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-delete-sync');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-penthouse');
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-ftpush');

 // define default task
 grunt.registerTask('default', ["browserSync", "watch"]);
};
```

*strong text*

Answer (score 0):

try `npm i -S pixrem` then retry your grunt command.